# How to to embed matplotlib.pyplot in wxpython?

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I made me a litle graph builded with matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3], [1,4,9], label='going up')#, color="red")
plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,2**3, 3**3], label='going down') #listeX, listeY, label[=]

leg = plt.legend(fancybox=True)#, loc='center')
#leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.5)

plt.axis([1,6,0,30])


plt.xlabel('text X ')
plt.ylabel('text Y ')

plt.show()
```

This example in the top works fine. But now I would like to embed this in my wxPython-Panel, but I don't knw how to do that. In the Internet I found a few examples how to doing this. But no example has shown me how to do.

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/MatplotlibFourierDemo
- [How to update a plot with python and Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160558/how-to-update-a-plot-with-python-and-matplotlib)

Do you have a example for me how to embed a matplotlib.pyplot-oject in wxpython?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737459/embedding-a-matplotlib-figure-inside-a-wxpython-panel

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/